# Custom Namespace on .NET web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, buildaction

So I wrote some custom classes and put them all in a namespace, call it "Sphere".

On my aspx.cs codebehind file, I have "using Sphere;" written. I know that this works because it's always worked until I copied this project to a new folder. Also, even when I click "view in web browser" everything works perfectly.

Simply, Visual Studio 08 is not recognizing the namespace and so I cannot build without an error and consequently cannot debug. Thanks for the help!

edit:
I have my namespace in my App_Code folder in a .cs file

Answer (score 3):

Are  your custom classes in a separate project? If so, you might need to add a reference to that project. If you have copied the project to a new folder, the path to your Sphere DLL/project in VS2008 might be broken.

Comment: I just have the namespace in a .cs file in my app_code folder

Answer (score 1):

I actually just figured it out:

My .cs files were set to "build action: content" rather than "compile." I right-clicked + properties all my files and changed the build action, and now it all works!

Comment: Please change the question title because this really had nothing to do with namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Check your references. It's possible VS is no longer finding them after you moved your application's folder.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like missing reference.

In your new project, do you have a reference to the project that defines the actual Sphere namespace?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like when you moved the files the references were broken. If the sphere classes are in a seperate dll try deleting and re-adding the reference. If it is just in a .de file be sure that filein the project is still in the relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you got this error:

> The type or namespace name 'CustomClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

And the reason the type was not in the assembly is that **App_Code** folder is specific folder for **Web Site Projects**. These files get compiled at runtime when they are deployed on server and not when you are building the project.
In **Web Application Project** every file has Build Action property. By default the classes files have value of Compile. But if the class is created in App_Code file it gets value Content. and does not get compiled when running as Application.
A the end the App_Code folder is not meant to be used in Web Application. Or as you figured it out you can manually change the Build Action to Compile.

I found the answer by searching these links:

1. [Vishal Joshi's Tangent - App_Code folder doesn’t work with Web Application Projects (WAPs)](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.co.at/2009/07/appcode-folder-doesnt-work-with-web.html)
2. [Build Action" property set to "Content" for class files inside App_Code folder](http://forums.asp.net/t/1847714.aspx?+Build+Action+property+set+to+Content+for+class+files+inside+App_Code+folder)